# Removing 1 of 5 divs without using a id

Tags: jquery

For various reasons, I cannot used an id to remove a div.

I basically have 5 divs, and if a specific if statement is true, I need to remove any one of those 5 divs.

I have placed a class in the div tags, which allows me to use $("div").length, which tells me how many divs I have.

Is it possible to remove any "one" of those without the div having an id?

Comment: Which one do you want to remove? Will it have it's own class? You've got to give us more information on the problem... Unless you just want to remove one at random... either way need some specifics please.

Comment: Any one.  It does not matter, just need to remove one.  They all have the same class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need ANY div removed, then the first div fits that requirement I guess.

```
$('div:first').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `eq()` jQuery selector will let you extract an element from a jQuery set by index. So, if you need to remove the third of the five divs, you would use something like this:

```
    $("div.class").eq(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery each function to parse your divs and find on which one you want to work : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 0):

If you did something like:

```
var length = $("div.myclass").length;
$("div.myclass:eq("+(length-1) +")").remove(); //Remove last div
```

Then you wouldn't need an id.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the CSS selector `nth-of-type()`. This would allow you to specify, say, the third matching element in a set, or any other arbitrary numbered position.

However, strangely, JQuery doesn't support this selctor -- it supports virtually every other selector known to man, and a few others besides, but not this one.

The good news, however, is that there is a JQuery plug-in called [More Selectors](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/moreSelectors) which adds this selector to JQuery, along with a few others.

Hope that helps.